# "unexpected token" error on my Conga Composer button

Tags: custom-button, error-messages, list-view, congo-composer

I have never created a Java Script button before but I tried to create a List View button on our Invoice Object. Use Case: select multiple invoices and run Conga Composer button to view what invoices with invoice lines would look like when selected invoices are consolidated.

Here is my current button:

```
var ids= {!GETRECORDIDS ($ObjectType.SCMC__Invoicing__c)}; 
var idsReport=ids.join("|"); 
var idsQuery=ids.join("'|'");

var CongaURL = "https://composer.congamerge.com" +
"?sessionId={!$Api.Session_ID}" + 
"&ServerUrl={!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_80}" + 
"&Id={!$User.X18_digit_User_ID__c}" + 
"&QueryId=aAQ5B0000008a34?pv0=" + idsQuery +
"&TemplateId=aAY5B0000004P7Z";
window.open( CongaURL, "Conga", "width=700,height=550,menubar=0" );
```

The error I am getting when I select 2 invoices and run the button:

> SCMC__Invoicing__r.Id = 'a6E5B0000008t41','a6E5B0000008t4A' LIMIT
>   25000
>                                           ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:1010 unexpected token: ','

Comment: Please refrain from asking for help in your posts, specially in the title as it is not representative of your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error stems from the fact that multiple values in a query should normally be written with "IN":

```
SCMC__Invoicing__r.Id IN ('a6E5B0000008t41','a6E5B0000008t4A')
```

It seems that you have unbalanced quotes, which may be throwing the entire thing off:

```
var idsQuery=ids.join("'|'");
```

Ends up creating a string like:

```
a6E5B0000008t41'|'a6E5B0000008t4A
```

While I suspect it probably needs to be quoted properly:

```
'a6E5B0000008t41'|'a6E5B0000008t4A'
```

In which case, you need to add some quotes in to your code:

```
var idsQuery="'"+ids.join("'|'")+"'";
```

A variant of this is mentioned in their [online help topic](https://support.getconga.com/Conga_Composer/Advanced_Composer_Solutions/Composer_Tips_and_Tricks/How_to_Create_a_Conga_Composer_List_View_button) here:

```
var ids= {!GETRECORDIDS( $ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem )};
var idsReport=ids.join("|");
var idsQuery=ids.join("'|'");
var CongaURL = "https://composer.congamerge.com" +
"?sessionId={!$Api.Session_ID}" +
"&ServerUrl={!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_80}" +
"&Id={!Opportunity.Id}" + 
"&ReportId=00OE0000000P57r?pv0=" + idsReport +
"&QueryId=a03o000000JuspY?pv0='" + idsQuery +"'";
window.open( CongaURL, "Conga", "width=700,height=550,menubar=0" );
```

They put the quotes in the URL part (`pv0='" + idsQuery +"'"`), and you probably accidentally overlooked them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here is the button now, still getting an error:WHERE SCMC__Invoicing__r.Id ='''a6E5B0000008t44','a6E5B0000008t4C'''ERROR at Row:1:Column:995
unexpected token: 'a6E5B0000008t44' {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.SCMC__Invoicing__c)}; 
var idsQuery="'"+ids.join("'|'")+"'";
var CongaURL ="https://composer.congamerge.com"+
"?sessionId={!$Api.Session_ID}"+ 
"&ServerUrl={!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_80}"+ 
"&Id={!$User.X18_digit_User_ID__c}" + 
"&QueryId=aAQ5B0000008a34?pv0='" + idsQuery +"'";
"&TemplateId=aAY5B0000004P7Z";